# ERROR con imagen al hacer zoom sale mal el POP UP/Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, imagen, modal

Estoy haciendo una página con varias imágenes modales, cuando le das click a la primera imagen aparece una grid con varias imágenes y para salir de ese modal hay que darle al botón "Cerrar". A su vez, cuando le das click a la primera imagen se hace otro modal que hace que se vea la imagen más de cerca, y se supone que al hacer click en cualquier parte de la pantalla que no sea la foto, debería cerrarse y volver a verse el grid con las 3 imágenes.

Problemas:

La imagen no se cierra, dandole al botón "Cerrar" sí. Pero así se cierra todos los modal y lo que me gustaría es que volviera a aparecer las 3 imágenes cuando se le de click al exterior de esta.
Al final queda distorsionada. No se que puedo hacer para que se adapte al formato que tiene y quede proporcionado.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.customer-logos').slick({
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1500,
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 520,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
  /*-------------Grid1--------------*/

.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 2%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40%, 1fr))
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  .gallery {
    padding: 2%;
    max-width: 150px!important;
  }
}


/*-------------Grid--------------*/


/*-------------Grid2--------------*/

.gallery2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 2%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30%, 1fr))
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  .gallery {
    padding: 2%;
    max-width: 150px!important;
  }
}


/*-------------Grid--------------*/

.modal-container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0vw;
  top: -10vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 2000vh;
  width: 107vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: -5vw;
  padding: 20vh 6vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.show {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}


/*.centrate{
                                    margin: 0;
                                    position: absolute;
                                    top: 50%; left: 50%;
                                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/

.centrate {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```html
<ul class="portfolio-grid work-4col alt-font text-center hover-option11 gutter-extra-large">
  <li class="grid-sizer"></li>
  <li class="grid-item animacion wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <a href="#" id="open">
      <div class="portfolio-img bg-extra-dark-gray"><img src="images/fotos_paginas/index/zancudo-led.jpg" alt="dfasfsda" /></div>
    </a>
    <span class="portfolio-item-title">Robots Zancudos LED</span>
  </li>



  <div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
    <a style="z-index: 3; float:left; position: fixed; left: 5%; bottom: 5%" class="btn btn-extra-large btn-white btn-rounded md-margin-15px-bottom sm-display-table sm-margin-lr-auto" id="close" href="#">Cerrar</a>

    <div class="centrate">

      <div class="gallery2">
        <img class="zoomable" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" alt="fsdfsdgs">
        <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xz44nnc/o5lkyivqw/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $('img.zoomable').css({
            cursor: 'pointer'
          }).live('click', function() {
            var img = $(this);
            var bigImg = $('<img />').css({
              'max-width': '100%',
              'max-height': '100%',
              'display': 'inline'
            });
            bigImg.attr({
              src: img.attr('src'),
              alt: img.attr('alt'),
              title: img.attr('title')
            });
            var over = $('<div />').text(' ').css({
              'height': '100%',
              'width': '100%',
              'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,.82)',
              'position': 'fixed',
              'top': 0,
              'left': 0,
              'opacity': 0.0,
              'cursor': 'pointer',
              'z-index': 9999,
              'text-align': 'center'
            }).append(bigImg).bind('click', function() {
              $(this).fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(this).remove();
              });
            }).insertAfter(this).animate({
              'opacity': 1
            }, 300);
          });
        </script>
        <img src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" alt="dfad">
        <img src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" alt="fsdfsf">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const open = document.getElementById('open');
    const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
    const close = document.getElementById('close');

    open.addEventListener('click', () => {
      modal_container.classList.add('show');
    });

    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
      modal_container.classList.remove('show');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hola. No se entiende bien lo que estás queriendo. Pero mirando el funcionamiento del código y la estructura, dedusco que los que quieres es mostrar cada imagen del modal de forma independiente y ampliada, luego cerrar la imágen sin cerrar el modal

Comment: Si te interesa replantear por completo tu código, te puedo compartir un trabajo que tengo y que hace algo similar. Pero voy a adaptar a tu código para que al ampliar la imagen, también muestre su título

Comment: Ningún problema, así aprendo otro método. Muchas gracias

Comment: No es otro lenguaje. Simplemente es CSS y jQuery 1 como el que tienes, pero un tanto diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es una opción por la que se puede optar a usar; con las mismas funcionalidades.

Abro un modal para ver tres imágenes. Luego para ver mas grande cada imagen con un click, esta se amplia mostrando un titulo y un texto adicional.

Al hacer click en cada imagen, se crea un nuevo div con `append()` desde una constante predefinido (plantilla) con una imagen incluido. Esta imagen es virgen, para poder recibir todos los tributos: `src`, `title` y `alt` de la imagen que se seleccionó.

```
  const nuevo = '<div class="div"><div class="cerrar"></div><img src="" alt="" title=""><div class="titular"><span class="titulo">Titulo</span><span class="info">Info</span></div></div>';
```

De esta forma se escribe el atributo de ésta imagen a la otra imagen:

```
// ésta imagen
let a = $(this).attr("src");

// a la nueva imagen
$(".div img").attr("src", a);
```

Todo esto haciendo click.
Y el siguiente es el ejemplo completo.

```js
const open = document.getElementById('open');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');
const close = document.getElementById('close');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container.classList.add('show');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  modal_container.classList.remove('show');
});



// Al clicar una imagen 
$(".zoomable").live("click", function(e) {

  // Crear un div para mostrar la imagen 

  // Estructura HTML  
  const nuevo = '<div class="div"><div class="cerrar"></div><img src="" alt="" title=""><div class="titular"><span class="titulo">Titulo</span><span class="info">Info</span></div></div>';

  // Mostrar la estructura HTML
  $(".gallery").append(nuevo);
  $(".div").fadeIn(300);

  // Usar los atributos de la imagen
  let a = $(this).attr("src");
  let b = $(this).attr("title");
  let c = $(this).attr("alt");

  // Escribir textos de los atributos de la imagen
  $(".div img").attr("src", a);
  $(".titulo").text(b);
  $(".info").text(c);

});

// Cerrar el div creado
$(".div .cerrar").live("click", function() {

  $(".div").fadeOut(300)

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}

body {
  font-family: 'Monserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #ddd
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}


/*****************************/

.modal-container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
  transition: 0.3s
}

.modal-container.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible
}

#close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px
}

.centrate {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90)
}

.gallery img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.div img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(0);
  width: 50%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 4rem);
  margin: auto
}

.div .titular {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  pointer-events: none
}

.titular span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: all;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2)
}

.titular .titulo {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff
}

.titular .info {
  text-align: left;
  color: #ccc
}

.cerrar {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
  transition: background 0.3s
}

.cerrar:hover {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 0, 0.90)
}
```

```html
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xz44nnc/o5lkyivqw/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


<button id="open" style="width:300px;height:50px;margin:auto;margin-left:calc(50% - 150px);margin-top:calc(25% - 50px)">Abrir modal</button>

<div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">

  <button id="close">Cerrar Modal</button>

  <div class="centrate">

    <div class="gallery">

      <img class="zoomable" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" title="Primera foto" alt="Informacion de esta imagen">
      <img class="zoomable" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" title="Foto 2" alt="Detalles">
      <img class="zoomable" src="https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/click-here-button-cursor-set-260nw-1792658299.jpg" title="Tercero" alt="fsdfsf">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente y además es mucho más intuitivo. Muchas gracias